# How much important is javascript for responsive websites with HTML5 & CSS3

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

Is it not possible to create Responsive site without .js?
Can any one share me the resources, where i can start learning from scratch to create responsive website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is, you would use media queries in your css files, or when calling them.

I separate my css files and name them like `layout_desktop`, `layout_mobile` and `layout_tablet`.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-device-width: 1024px)" href="layout_desktop.css" />
```

[Here is the reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)

**UPDATE**

If you would like to do it in one CSS file, you can add queries around certain blocks of code, like this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 700px) { /* CSS code goes here */ }
```

Comment: Thanks @josh, i liked the naming for the CSS file. But will it be problem if i write all media queries in one common.css file

Comment: Thanks @Josh i'm confused with 'min-width' & 'max-width' & lot more. how to understand this media queries. where can i study about media queries in details.

Comment: @josh don't refer to w3schools (the fools)... mozilla is the place to be: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, JS is used for interactivity. CSS is used to control responsiveness -- that is, displaying elements differently (or not at all!) depending on viewport size and/or orientation.

A good resource to get started would be http://www.adamkaplan.me/grid or a framework like Bootstrap or Foundation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible!. It's even better imho. Responsiveness is just the art of writing a Stylesheet (CSS) that adapts to the size of the screen. The general guideline is to use percentage widths instead of pixels. What I usually do is set a max width on the main container:

```
.wrapper {
    max-width: 1260px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

This looks like a complete guide http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/responsive-web-design/

Comment: Thanks @Jonas. Link is helpful

Answer (score 0):

You don't need JavaScript to create responsive layout. The only thing you need is well written CSS with HTML.

For more flexibility in responsive layout, we often uses `@media` queries. These however are [not supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries) in older browsers (IE8). To add support for media queries, we can use polyfils (litle pieces of javascript that add support for missing properties in older browsers).

**Edit**:

To answer your question:
As Jonas allready pointed out, there is no 'best' standard. In responsive design there are 2 approaches: Mobile first or Dekstop first.

Mobile first means, you first make it look good on small screens. Then you start expanding the screen size untill it looks like sh*t. There you add a 'breakpoint' and add extra styles using a @media selector untill it look good. then you repeat the exapand - fix proces.

Desktop first is exactly the same, but here you start on large screens first. You make the screen smaller untill it looks like sh*t, fix it with @media selectors and repeat.

Comment: Thanks @Pinoniq. What are the standard media queries which we must target.

Comment: I think having "standard media queries" is a bad habit. You need to decide media queries, depending on when they would make sense (in order to keep the page readable and good looking)